# Push Notification not registering with requested tag

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am following the Azure Mobile Services e-book for setting up Push Notifications:

https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/android/#registering-for-push-notifications

But am having problems with registering with a Tag:

```
            var registrationId = GcmClient.GetRegistrationId(RootView);
            //var push = client.GetPush();
            //await push.RegisterAsync(registrationId);

            var installation = new DeviceInstallation
            {
                InstallationId = client.InstallationId,
                Platform = "gcm",
                PushChannel = registrationId
            };
            // Set up tags to request
            installation.Tags.Add("topic:Sports");
            // Set up templates to request
            PushTemplate genericTemplate = new PushTemplate
            {
                Body = @"{""data"":{""message"":""$(message)""}}"
            };
            installation.Templates.Add("genericTemplate", genericTemplate);

            // Register with NH
            var response = await client.InvokeApiAsync<DeviceInstallation, DeviceInstallation>(
                $"/push/installations/{client.InstallationId}",
                installation,
                HttpMethod.Put,
                new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

I have ensured that the tag is listed in the Azure Portal as a "Client Requested" tag, but still my registrations appear without the tag in the Device Registrations:

[image]

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: I haven't found anything wrong in your code. I suggest you add a breakpoint in your code to check whether the device&topic register code is executed or not. Please also check the tag which added to your portal is "topic:Sports" not "Sports".

Comment: @Amor-MSFT See answer below.  The e-book is out of date and now wrong. Very frustrating :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the e-book is out of date and is dealing with the old version of Mobile Services instead of Azure App Service Mobile Apps (seriously, how is anyone supposed to google around for the different versions when they are named so similarly?!)

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-quickstart/blob/master/README.md#push-to-users

(Emphasis is mine)

> When a mobile app registers for push notifications using an Azure App Service Mobile Apps backend, there are two default tags that can get added to the registration in Azure Notification Hubs: the installation ID, which is unique to the app on a given device, and the user ID, which is only added when the user has been previously authenticated. **Any other tags that get supplied by the client are ignored, which is by design. (Note that this differs from Mobile Services, where the client could supply any tag and there were hooks into the registration process on the backend to validate tags on incoming registrations.)**
>
> Because the client can’t add tags and at the same time there are no service-side hooks into the push notification registration process, the client needs to do the work of adding new tags to a given registration.

So the reason it was not working was because the code in the e-book is out of date and does not work with the latest version.

I had to create an Api Controller to allow the Tag to be registered using the code in the above link.  Then the client apps have to call this endpoint just after they have called the two commented methods in the sample code in my question.